# Japanese character not displayed properly in Java

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding, character

I have text box and a button. I am entering Japanese characters like こんにちは in text box.

When I click on button email is sent with the text in text box.

But when email receive it displays some junk character instead Japanese characters.

Can anybody please tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the encodings being used?

Comment: Show the code you use to build the message body

Comment: String str= myEntity.getTextBoxValue();StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();strb.append(str);return strb.toString();

Comment: @user2448398 You can simplify that to `return myEntity.getTextBoxValue();`.

Comment: but before appending to StringBuilder , if i do System.out.println(str); that time only it shows junk character. 
also I used charset as content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: @user2448398 You need to explain more about what it's you're trying to do. Now you're talking about HTML charset encoding. How are you using the HTML code in your Java program?

Comment: i have jsp page on which there is text box and a button. I am entering value in text box in jsp page. I am capturing that value in java side.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you are using a character set that supports Japanese characters, like Unicode.

For instance, when creating a `String` object there is an overloaded constructor where you can specify character encoding:

```
byte[] utf8Characters = { /* UTF-8 encoded characters */ };
String s = new String(characters, "UTF-8"); // Decode bytes using UTF-8.
```

Also when converting Strings to bytes (ie when streaming data) you can use:

```
byte[] utf8EncodedBytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Encode to UTF-8.
```

If you do not specify character encoding it will default to some charset which might not support the characters you need.

Java Doc says:
"The default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically depends upon the locale and charset being used by the underlying operating system."

Comment: Hello snipes83,Thanks for your reply.I tried things as you suggested but still I am seeing Junk charcters. I tried as , byte[] b= myEntity.getTextBoxValue().getBytes("UTF-8");
String value = new String(b, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(value); // it prints π??π??π?¬π?? characters

Comment: @user2448398 If your program gives you junk when printing the String given by `myEntity.getTextBoxValue()`, then the problem is probably in how `myEntity` handles the charset encoding. What does `myEntity` represent?

Comment: it just simply holds value entered in the text box. public class MyEntity {private String textBoxValue; //getter,setter of this}.

Comment: @user2448398 and how do you set the string value of `MyEntity`? From a HTML form?

Comment: yes I verified ,my javascript is also already set using UTF-8 ,<script src="js/data.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"/>.Any other suggesions ?

Comment: anyone please suggest any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

im not really sure if you are using java servlets but if you do, you can try this

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```